# How to differentiate the explicitly assigning null to the field or field that is not in the json file for @PATCH

Tags: json, rest, patch

I am using `@PATCH` for the partial update of the record.
My table is `emp`:

```
empId - Int
lastName -String
firstName - String
city - String
desc - String
```

Patch json file for `emp/1`:

```json
{"city" : "NULL", "lastName": "newLastName"}
```

How can I pass this to the pl/sql procedure (how the sql query can be constructed only to update `city` and `lastName`) and how to differentiate between explicity city set to NULL and `desc` is not found in json.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways on how to deal with that kind of situation, I implemented at least two different ones:

- Send a JSON document that represents the updated resource

  - Either you require the client to always send the complete JSON document (not a partial one) so you always get *all* values in a single request (easy). Absent values mean that the field is supposed to be `null`.
  - Or you allow the client to send a partial JSON document but then you need a unique identifier to distinguish between an absent field (not to touch) and a field that needs to be overridden with `null` (harder but not impossible).
- Send a JSON document that contains operations on a resource, e. g. `{ "operation": "update", "field": "city", "value": "New City" }` which replaces the old value of `city` with `New City` or `{ "operation": "delete", "field": "description" }` which deletes `description` (requires parsing patches differently).

Comment: I need to update the fileds only that are in json file

Comment: So you need to pass the values from the incoming request into the algorithm that does the update. As you hadn't added any code examples this is all we can do right now.